# Aspose: while I am trying to generate a ppt from csv, the ppt is getting corrupted?

Tags: powerpoint, aspose

Aspose: while I am trying to generate a powerpoint from a csv file, the powerpoint is always getting corrupted?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you please share that how are creating the copy of the presentation. Please also share what you meant by copying content of file from previous to new one. How are you managing this? Unfortunately, without provision of complete issue, sample project and source presentation I may not be able to help you further in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Aspose APIs to create PowerPoint presentation from CSV, you can use Aspose.Cells to convert CSV to PDF and then Aspose.Pdf to convert PDF to PowerPoint e.g.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Sample.csv");
workbook.Save("Sample.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);

Document pdfDocument = new Document("Sample.pdf");
pdfDocument.Save("Presentation1.pptx", Aspose.Pdf.SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential Presentation](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation) can be used to generate PowerPoint from CSV. [Sample code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CSVToPresentation-2144587754.zip)

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.